# pyrocms files url not decoding image

Tags: file, .htaccess, gzip, pyrocms

I have pyrocms installed and it does not show or decodes any files format.

http://2013.chocolate6.com/chocolate6pyro/files/cloud_thumb/9

it returns 
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

The webpage at http://2013.chocolate6.com/chocolate6pyro/files/cloud_thumb/9 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

Any help suggestion,I will be highly greatfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your config.php file to the following.

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```